# Disable weakened protocols/ciphers in WSO2AM-1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2AM(1.10.0) is used in my organization as API gateway. Before releasing it to production, there are a few weakened protocols/ciphers found by a security company and they suggest disable these protocols as below,

1. TLSv1.0
2. 3DES based ciphers
3. 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman groups

Could anyone please suggest me how to turn them off and any side-effects?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable TLSv1.0 by removing it from repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml file.

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9443"
                bindOnInit="false"
                sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

Ciphers can be disabled editing same file ciphers section.

```
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security#). However, there are some known issues if you are running on jdk1.7. Refer [here.](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4745)

Comment: Thanks heaps your responds, it is very helpful.

Comment: Hi, it is working for management console. however, how can I apply the same settings to API connections? I created a new thread for the queation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837167/remove-weakened-protocols-in-wso2-1-10-0. Could you please take a look? thanks a lot.