# remove weakened protocols in WSO2 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an answer which can disable unwanted protocols/ciphers (TLSv1.0 and 3DES based ciphers) for management console in Tomcat(port: 9443), [Disable weakened protocols/ciphers in WSO2AM-1.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771627/disable-weakened-protocols-ciphers-in-wso2am-1-10-0).

[image: results_1]

however, I have no idea how can I apply the same settings to API connection in Axis server (Port 443) like below,

[image: example API]

The API connection using 443 port seems still support TLSv1 as tested by sslsscan,

[image: results]

Thanks,Sean

Comment: Have you changed the pass-through settings in  repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file ?

<transportReceiver name="passthru-https" class="org.wso2.carbon.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
    <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter>
    ......
</transportReceiver>

Comment: Thanks heaps, it is working adding the httpsProtocols into  <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener"></transportReceiver> section.

Comment: Glad to help. Posted the same as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following pass-through settings in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file.

```
<transportReceiver name="passthru-https" class="org.wso2.carbon.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSL‌​Listener"> <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter> ...... </transportReceiver>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. By the way, do you have any idea about 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman groups used in WSO2 A, which is asked to disable?

Comment: You can find answers in this article :)
https://dzone.com/articles/wso2-products-resolving-err-ssl-weak-ephemeral-dh